# How to find the path of Database file in Android Emulator?

Tags: android

I am executing some sqlite query in the Android emulator. I want to know which path that database files are storing. Pls give me some idea how to find it. If u can provide me some code snippet.

urs,
s.kumaran.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The databases are usually stored in

```
/data/data/your.applications.package/databases
```

and you can use the `adb shell` to `cd` to that directory and open the db with `sqlite3`.

Comment: Hi josef, thanks for ur response i can see that database in the location what you said and used terminal emulator to see that file, but i wish to copy that file from emulator to my system desktop.Can you please tell me how to do that.I don't have any idea about that can pls guide me step by step how to proceed.

regards,
s.kumaran

Comment: You can use the `adb pull` command to copy files from your emulator or phone. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#copyfiles

Comment: is it possible to programmatically obtain the database file path ?

Comment: You can use getDatabasePath() and get the database path directly from Activity

Answer (score 1):

Your Project Name\app\build\intermediates\assets\debug
Or:
Your Project Name\app\src\main\assets

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio

View -> Tool Windows -> Device File Explorer

in Window "Device File Explorer" find
data/data/YOUR_PACKET_NAME/databases/YOU_PROJECT_TITLE

Save as where you want
open sqlite file via "BD Browser for SQLite" (if you use MAC OS)